# How to store the output of a Bash command inside >() in a variable?

Tags: bash, shell

I have this:

```
tee < /some/big/file >(wc -c) >(md5sum) | ...
```

Instead of writing the results of `wc -c` and `md5sum` to stdout, I want to store the results into two variables for later processing. I don't want to read the file more than once. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: [UUOC](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html): use `tee < /some/big/file` instead of `cat /some/big/file | tee`.

Comment: To clarify my question, I want to avoid reading the big file more than once, and the wc and md5 commands are really just placeholders for some actual, more complicated commands.

Comment: That's important.  You should edit your question.

Comment: What I mean by "that's important" is that if you want placeholder commands, use commands that aren't real.  For example, we can understand that `cmd1` is a placeholder, but `wc -c` is not obviously a placeholder, because it is a real command.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002

Comment: I chose wc and md5sum because I wanted to convey that the command outputs are very small (but obviously I didn't do a great job of that). The output size can sway what's a better solution.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson That's a link with generally useful info. Are you trying to say that the solution requires temp files or named pipes?

Comment: Yes, as in Dietrich's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question... but you only have to read the file once, and you don't have to use `tee`.

```
SIZE=$(wc -c /some/big/file)
MD5=$(md5 /some/big/file)
```

So, how many times does this read the file?  Once.  This is because `wc -c` doesn't actually read the file, it just looks at how long it is and reports back.  Here are my tests:

```
$ time wc -c /big/file >/dev/null
real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
$ time wc -c </big/file >/dev/null
real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
$ time cat /big/file | wc -c >/dev/null
real    0m52.945s
user    0m0.160s
sys     0m19.612s
```

The lesson: don't mix `tee` (or `cat`) with `wc -c`, because it's a *big* waste of time.  Just do the `md5` normally and don't worry about `wc -c`.

Note: The reason why `wc -c <file` is fast is because it gets an ordinary file handle, just as if `wc` had called `open()` itself.

### Pipe performance

You should almost never use `cat` in a pipe.

```
cat file | cmd    # slow
cmd <file         # fast
```

Calling `cat` usually means creating an extra process which serves no purpose.  In some cases, as with `wc -c`, it actually slows down the program after the pipe.  I mean, you could stick `cat` anywhere you like, but it's just silly:

```
echo 'hello, world' | cat
cat file.txt | less
cat file.txt | cat | less
cat file.txt | cat | sort | cat | cat | uniq | cat >file_unique.txt
```

This is better:

```
echo 'hello, world'
less file.txt
sort file.txt | uniq >file_unique.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a FIFO and temporary files.

```
input=/some/big/file
mkfifo tmp
wc -l <tmp >wc.out &
md5=$(tee <"$input" tmp | md5sum)
fg
lines=$(cat wc.out)
rm tmp
rm wc.out
```

Comment: You're using two different variable names, `INPUT` and `FILE`, which should be the same. In order to avoid potential name collision with shell variables, it's a good habit to not use all-caps variable names.

Answer (score 0):

May be someone can offer something better, but I think your best shot is

```
LINES=$(cat /some/big/file | wc -l)
MD5=$(cat /some/big/file | md5)
```

The reason, I think it's the best shot, is that one way or another you will have to apply two separate operations to the content of the file. So unless you have a command that knows how to do it at the same time you will have to read it twice.
Beyond reading it twice, that should be a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can export a variable from the `>()` ([Process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)). If you don't mind redirecting the output to temporary files you can then just read the file into a variable.

Example

```
tee < /some/big/file >(cmd1 > tmp1) >(cmd2 > tmp2) | ...
CMD1_OUT=$(cat tmp1)
CMD2_OUT=$(cat tmp2)
```